# How to expand a 3D rectangle to show more rectangles when clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to 3D shapes in HTML and CSS. How can I create a 3D rectangle and when clicked on it the rectangle should show 3 more 3D rectangles below it and these rectangles should be clickable.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var vis = false;
var container = document.getElementById("c");
container.onclick = toggleVisibility;

function toggleVisibility() {
 container.className = vis ? 
  "container" : "container vis";
 vis = !vis;
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateZ(25deg);
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.side-vert {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.side-hor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-15px);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-15px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(145px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-15px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(145px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(15px);
}

.r {
  transform: translateZ(45px);
}

.g {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.b {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(-45px);
}

.r > * {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.g > * {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.b > * {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.vis > * {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="c" class="container">
  <div class="box r">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side-vert left"></div>
    <div class="side-vert right"></div>
    <div class="side-hor top"></div>
    <div class="side-hor bottom"></div>
    <div class="side front">
  <img src="https://bmdinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/stack-overflow-logo.png">
 </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="box g">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side-vert left"></div>
    <div class="side-vert right"></div>
    <div class="side-hor top"></div>
    <div class="side-hor bottom"></div>
    <div class="side front">
  <img src="https://bmdinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/stack-overflow-logo.png">
 </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="box b">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side-vert left"></div>
    <div class="side-vert right"></div>
    <div class="side-hor top"></div>
    <div class="side-hor bottom"></div>
    <div class="side front">
     <img src="https://bmdinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/stack-overflow-logo.png">
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

PS: mainly inspired by [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/front-end-challenge-accepted-css-3d-cube/) , also, [here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unhalium/jk1ekmwu/) I made with SCSS stylesheet to see the correlations between $dim and $depth and the different transforms

Comment: Thanks @halim this is really helpful .... I am trying to make a small tweak to in your code to tilt rectangles back a little more along x-axis some thing like this http://i.imgur.com/ZsOb8l8.jpg so front face is leaning back more  ... is there a an easy way to do that

Comment: Hey @whippits you can change 'rotateX(40deg)' in the '.container' CSS to something like 60deg and then increase the gap between rectangles by changing 'translateZ' parameter in the .r .g .b classes. I updated [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unhalium/jk1ekmwu/) to do just that